# Visual Studio find new line in resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search

I have a .resx file and I would like to find all the keys where the value finishes with a new line.

My file is full of items like this :

```
<data name="KEY" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>My Text
</value>
    <comment>My comment</comment>
```

In the example there is a new line at the end of the value and I would like to find a regular expression to find all the items where there is a new line at the end of the value.

I've tried  `\r?\n</value>` but it doesn't seem to work. (following the help : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Could you help me ?

Comment: Do you want that runtime or design-time (in VS) ? As XML nodes or as Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` character. Try this:

```
\r?\n<\/value>
```